# 3 select anidados usando PHP,JQUERY, AJAX Y MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

mi inconveniente es el siguiente:   estoy desarrollando un sistema de turnos online y en una de las secciones quiero que la secretaria pueda crear un turno. El problema se da al querer anidar 3 select usando ajax, ya que me funciona para mostrar datos en el primer y segundo select pero no en el tercero (se muestra vacío). El select 1 elige el profesional, el select 2 elige la fecha disponible y el select 3 elige el rango horario entre los horarios q atiende ese profesional. Si al tercer select lo ubico en otra pantalla me funciona correctamente con PHP via POST, por lo q creo q el problema está en el ajax  que comunica con el tercer select (creo q no me toma el script para calcular el dia de la fecha seleccionada). No tengo problemas con las sentencias en SQL ya q con PHP solo y en pantallas separadas funciona bien. Saludos y espero q puedan ayudarme
ACA VA EL CODIGO:

```
//página principal para seleccionar profesional,fecha y horario
 <?php

session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"/>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Tipoo").on('change', function () {
$('#Tipo3').find('option').remove().end().append('<option 
value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');
$("#Tipoo option:selected").each(function () {
 var pp=$(this).val();
        $.post("./estudio1.php", { pp: pp }, function(data){
            $("#Tipo2").html(data);
        });         
    });
  });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Tipo2").on('change', function () {
$("#Tipo2 option:selected").each(function () {
var elegido=$(this).val();
$.post("./estudio2.php", { elegido: elegido }, function(data){
$("#Tipo3").html(data);
   });          
   });
     });
     });  </script>
```

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>&nbsp ESTUDIO</h2> <br> <br><br><br>
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="prof">
<label id="Tipo"><b> Seleccione Profesional</b> </label><br>
<select id="Tipoo" name="Profesional" required>
<option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione:</option>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT `profesionales`.*,`profesionales_tipoestudios`.*
FROM `profesionales`
INNER JOIN `profesionales_tipoestudios` ON 
`profesionales_tipoestudios`.`id_profesional` = `profesionales`.`idp`
 WHERE id_tipoestudio=\"$_SESSION[ides]\"";

$query = $conexion -> query ($sql);
while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

if($_POST['Profesional']==$valores['idp']){

echo '<option value="'.$valores['idp'].'" 

 selected>'.$valores['apellido']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$valores['nombre'].
'</option>';
}else{
 echo '<option 
value="'.$valores['idp'].'">'.$valores['apellido']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".     
$valores['nombre'].'</option>';

}
$_SESSION['idpr']=$_POST['Profesional'];**texto en negrita**
}

    ?>     
    </select> <br><br><br>

    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['Profesional'])){

    $sql2 = "SELECT idp,apellido,nombre FROM profesionales WHERE 
idp=\"$_POST[Profesional]\"";
$query2 = $conexion -> query ($sql2);
while($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
$_SESSION['aaa']=     
$valores2['apellido']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$valores2['nombre'];
                    }

    }

    ?>      

<label><b>Seleccione Fechas disponibles</b></label> <br>
<select id="Tipo2" name="fe"  onchange="go();" required >

</select> <br><br>

<label><b>Seleccione Horarios disponibles</b></label> <br>
<select id="Tipo3" name="hh" onchange=this.form.submit() required >

   <?php 


    ?>
    </select>

  <?php 

  ?>
  </div>        
 </form><div class="out" align="left" ><button 
 id="volver"onClick="history.go(-1);"style="color:white;margin- 
top:-15px;margin-left:550px;">volver</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

// pagina para cargar el  segundo select (fechas disponibles)

```
$html = '';
<?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';
$idp=$_POST['pp'];
$elegir=$_POST['elegido'];
$queryf = $conexion -> query ("SELECT DISTINCT `fecha_atencion`.fecha ,    `profesionales`.* from `profesionales`INNER JOIN `fecha_atencion` ON 
`fecha_atencion`.`id_prof` = `profesionales`.`idp` WHERE id_prof = $idp 
order by `fecha_atencion`.`fecha`");
?><option value="0" selected disabled>Seleccione:</option>
<?php
while ($valores1 = mysqli_fetch_array($queryf)) {
 echo '<option value="'.$valores1['fecha'].'">'.date("d-m-y", 
(strtotime($valores1['fecha']))).'</option>'; }
 echo $html;
  ?>




  // pagina para cargar el tercer select (horarios)

$html = '';
<?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php'; 
//sacar el dia de esa fecha
$elegir=$_POST['elegido'];
$idp=$_POST['pp'];
$fecha = date('l', strtotime($elegir));
if ($fecha== "Monday") {
$diatrabajo="Lunes";
}else{
if ($fecha== "Tuesday") {
$diatrabajo="Martes";
}else{
if ($fecha== "Wednesday") {
$diatrabajo="Miercoles";
}else{
if ($fecha== "Thursday") {
$diatrabajo="Jueves";
}else{
if ($fecha== "Friday") {
$diatrabajo="Viernes";
    }
  }
 }}}

    $query = $conexion -> query("SELECT `rango_horario`.*, `dias`.* FROM 
 `dias`
INNER JOIN `rango_horario` ON `rango_horario`.`dia_rango` = `dias`.`id`
WHERE `dias`.`dia`=\"$diatrabajo\" and `rango_horario`.`id_prof` =\"$idp\"");
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $ini=$valores['hora_inicio'];
        $fin=$valores['hora_fin'];
        $_SESSION['ini']=$ini;
        $_SESSION['fin']=$fin;
    }

    $query5 = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE horario 
BETWEEN \"$ini\" AND \"$fin\" ");
       ?>  <option value="0" selected disabled>Seleccione:</option><?php
    while ($valores3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query5)) {

            echo '<option 
value="'.$valores3['horario'].'">'.$valores3['horario'] .'</option>';
        }
     ?>
<?php 
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: No sería más fácil tener 3 selects separados que hasta que no insertas un valor en el 1º no se muestre el 2º y así sucesivamente?

Comment: @matahombres hola, precisamente así estaba antes, pero la idea es darle un efecto más agradable a la vista del usuario y una interacción más fluida con la página vía AJAX. De todos modos ya pude corregir el problema convirtiendo de PHP A JQUERY  el script para sacar el dia, pasando todo a una funcion de AJAX. GRACIAS POR COMENTAR.

Answer (score 1):

Aca va la función que soluciono mi problema, espero que le sirva a alguien:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
     $("#Tipo2").change(function(){
         $("#Tipo2 option:selected").each(function () {
        var elegido=$('#Tipo2').val()
         var ff=new Date(elegido)
         var numDiaSem = ff.getDay(); //getDay() devuelve el dia de la semana.(0-6).
         var diasSemana = new array("Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes");
            var diaLetras = diasSemana[ff.getDay()];//El día de la semana en letras. 
       getDay()devuelve el dia de la semana.(0-6).
            var pp=$('#Tipoo').val()
                var devolver = diaLetras; 
               $.post("./estudio2.php", { devolver: devolver, pp: pp}, 
function(dta){
                $("#Tipo3").html(dta);

            });
                 });
    });
    });
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad tienes 2 cuentas diferentes en el sitio?

Comment: No,tengo una sola cuenta, me respondí a mi mismo sin querer

Comment: @Joaquin ya arreglamos el problema de tus cuentas.